# It is possible to set custom key bindings with libmpv C/C++?

Tags: c++, qt, mpv

i'm using libmpv as video player backend for my Qt/c++ application and i can't find any way to set custom key bindings without an input.conf file or at least using lua scripting from the terminal so i can send it through mpv_command().

I looked for the way of MPV_EVENTS but i only was able to receive mouse events.
I tried using Qt events but of course, if the user touch the video area, the Qt widget can't keep the focus because the embedded mpv is in fact another window.
I couldn't find in the documentation an argument to set custom key bindings from terminal.
I couldn't find anything related on google for that!.
I don't want to provide and maintain a whole custom mpv source code with the application just for a custom key binding.

In the official documentation there's nothing related with that in the section of libmpv or command line arguments. I only found an approach for plugins made with Lua "mp.add_key_binding()" but nothing with pure c/c++ libmpv library.

Is there's something i'm missing or for now the only way to do that is modifying the mpv source code?
Sorry if i'm not clear enough, i not an expert speaking English but thank for your patience!.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply embedding the native mpv window into your own window, there's not much you can do. `input.conf` or lua scripting are the ways to go.

If you want true customization possibilities though, what you want to do is use the render api instead, documented in [`render.h`](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/libmpv/render.h).

You will need to keep your own OpenGL context and use the API functions to render into it. Then you control the window, and can do whatever you want with it. How to do that exactly is too large of a scope for this answer, but the documentation on the header explains it well.

Since this is only a rendering API, there will be no default key bindings. Or any input functionality, really. You will have to implement it all yourself. Again, how to do that exactly with OpenGL + Qt is way too big of a scope for this answer.

Comment: Oh! well, i though that before, but i realize that it will reduce the number of hardware that can use my app, i'm using libmpv because it render video pretty decent on old machines, something that libvlc doesn't do that well (generate artifacts), and also my app is meant to be uses with streaming media and the GStreamer backend of Qt6 is horrible for that on linux(too much drop frames errors and completely lack of sound on seek methods), embeded mpv was the better choice sinse i don't have to deal with ffmpeg itself and render with openGL could give a huge lack of performance to low resourcePC

Comment: There should be no change on what hardware you can support by using the render api. All you are doing is switching from "mpv handles the OpenGL context" to "you handle the openGL context".